# Auto sync multiple sql tables with different table structure

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization

I'm going to build a new version of my website. The old one is written in Cakephp and for the new one I'm going to use Laravel for that I need to split some large tables into smaller ones.

[image]

An example is given above.

But till the development of the new project complete, I need to sync data between these tables.
I cant use Cron or Replication in this situation. Coz Cron job will take time, I cant update the Old code coz it will also take time.

So how do I do this?

Comment: Use trigger logic if these 2 databases are processed by the same MySQL instance.

Comment: Would a script that reads the old data and converts it to the new data not suffice? Once your new site is ready you execute the script for the last time, and replace the old site.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I cant use that coz I'm going to build this website in modules, once a module completes development I will restrict the access to that module from the old site and give access to the new module.

Comment: I see. In that case MySQL triggers, as suggested by Akina, might indeed be a good solution.